# How do I state that two lists have the same length?

Tags: prolog

I need to know how to compare the length of two lists in Prolog. This is what I have so far:

```
sum(N1,N2) :-
    checklength(N1,N2).

checklength(N1,N2) :-
    L1 is length(N1,What),
    L2 is length(N2,What),
    Comp(L1,L2).

Comp(L1,L2) :-
    L1=:=L2.
```

Answer (score 9):

Of course, the answer from CapelliC is perfect, but you can try also the "standard" method of approaching this problem:

```
same_length([],[]).
same_length([_|L1],[_|L2]) :- same_length(L1, L2).
```

Comment: `sameLength/2` is a slight better name than `checklength/2`. Much better than both names is `same_length/2`.

Comment: Your solution has better termination properties than CapelliCs solution: Consider `same_length(L,[])`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using SWI-Prolog, then you can simply use `same_length/2` predicate.

Comment: `same_length/2`is **not** a built-in predicate. It's a library predicate and its library is being auto-loaded. You can always use the standard `predicate_property/2` predicate to check the properties, including `built_in`, of a predicate.

Answer (score 2):

you can use unification:

```
checklength(N1,N2):-
    length(N1,What),
    length(N2,What).
```

this will succeed only if N1 and N2 have the same length.

Btw `L1 is length(N1,What)` doesn't make sense. length/2 is a predicate, not a function.
That is, it will succeed or fail, but doesn't 'return' a value.
Otoh, is/2 expects an arithmetic expression as right operand.

*edit*

```
checklength(N1,N2,R1,R2):-
    length(N1,L1),
    length(N2,L2),
    (   L1 < L2
    ->  lpad(L1,L2,N1,R1), R2 = N2
    ;   L2 < L1
    ->  lpad(L2,L1,N2,R2), R1 = N1
    ;   (R1,R2) = (N1,N2)
    ).

lpad(A,A,L,L) :- !.
lpad(A,B,L,[0|T]) :- A < B, C is A+1, lpad(C,B,L,T).
```

Comment: What i want to do is not just compare the length but if the length is not equal then i want to append zero at the start of the list. Hence i  need to store the size somewhere and then append that many zeros

Comment: @user3342812 do you mean *prepend* zeroes to the list?

Comment: @user3342812: ok, maybe you should mention your wishes in your question... anyway, see my edit for a possible way to do...